# Find area of $\triangle ABC$ if $a^2+b^2 + c^2 = 6$ and $a^4 + b^4 +c^4 = 14$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find area of $\triangle ABC$ if $a^2+b^2 + c^2 = 6$ and $a^4 + b^4 +c^4 = 14$.

if acute triangle, I tried like this. but too hard to calculate and problem is type of triangle is not given. Is there some easy way?

$a^2 = x^2 + h^2$

$b^2 = h^2 +(c-x)^2 = h^2 + c^2 -2cx + x^2 $

then, $x= \frac{(a^2 + c^2 - b^2)} {2c}$

so, $h^2 = \frac{(-a^4 - b^4 - c^4 +2a^2b^2 + 2b^2 c^2 + 2c^2 a^2 )}{(4c^2)}$

$(a^2 + b^2 +c^2 )^2 = a^4 + b^4 + c^4 +2(a^2b^2 + b^2 c^2 + c^2 a^2)$

then $2(a^2b^2 + b^2 c^2 + c^2 a^2 )= 22$

let S= Area

$S^2 = (c^2 h^2)/4 = (-a^4 - b^4 - c^4 + 2a^2 b^2 + 2b^2c^2 +2 c^2a^2) / 16 = 1/2$

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: thank you for advice. I'll try to do.

Comment: What type of triangle is $ABC$ ?

Comment: type of triangle is not given

Comment: Are $a,b,c$ integer or can they be any real value ?

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit a,b, and c cannot all be integers as there is no integer solution to $a^2+b^2+c^2 = 6$ such that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are all the lengths of the sides of a triangle.

Comment: @parafoo Just wanted to confirm it from the O.P

Comment: I get $1/2$ as the searched area

Comment: You might want to look at Heron's formula

Comment: One version of [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron's_formula) is $$\verb/Area/ = \frac14\sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2-2(a^4+b^4+c^4)}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner - I think that $\frac12$ may be the square of the area

Comment: @achillehui Shhh..! *Avoid answering questions in comment.*

Comment: There are many differently shaped triangles which satisfy $a^2+b^2 + c^2 = 6$ and $a^4 + b^4 +c^4 = 14$.  The simplest is probably $\sqrt{1}, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}$

Answer (score 1):

Your method works for obtuse triangles as well, so it is also correct. If angle $C$ is obtuse (the angle opposite side $c$), then the angles of the two smaller triangles will still make sense. The only time this will not happen is if angle $C > 180º$.

Much more simply however, is Achille's comment that uses alternative version of Heron's formula:

$$\text{Area} = \frac{1}{4} \sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2 - 2(a^4+b^2+c^4)}$$

so the area is equal to $\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{6^2 - 2 \times 14} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.